# JSP file is automatically downloading instead of displaying content in Spring Boot app, how to resolve?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am working on spring boot web application project.
when ever I run spring boot web app It runs well, but in the browser when I excess this web app content, my jsp file automatically downloads instead of displaying content.

Below Spring boot first application:

```
package com.springboot.web;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootFirstApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootFirstApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Below one is Controller:

```
package com.springboot.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class mainController {

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Below one is application.properties file:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
server.port=9091
```

Below one is pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>springmvcboot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringBootFirst</name>
    <description>web project spring boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

below one is my jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is my Home Jsp</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I solve it ?

Comment: JSP is only supported in WAR files not JAR files (and come with limitations) as mentioned in the documentation. I would suggest to use something like Thymeleaf in the current day and age.